# What to do if an edit war starts?

Tags: discussion, editing

From the answer posted in this post [Is it approperiate to immediately edit low-quality questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/is-it-approperiate-to-immediately-edit-low-quality-questions), We are not allowed to change the content fundamentally. Thus I was rolling back to [this version of an answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/12656/revisions) because another user is fundamentally changing its contents. And then he goes and roll back to his edit.

What should I do in this case ?

Note: User has been told why he is not allowed to do so, but he kept rolling back.

Comment: Low quality question editing guidelines are not the same as improving and fixing an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215311/221866

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1150/3487

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But in the case where the original poster is unwilling to accept the edits and actively rejects them — please do not force the issue. It just leads to heartache. When in doubt, move on. There’s no shortage of editing opportunities, in fact, more are being written every minute. There are thousands of users who would appreciate reasonable edits that improve their post. Do not fight an edit war over a crumb of bread — there’s nothing there worth fighting for! It’s easier to just move on and get work done than create pain all out of proportion to the importance of the individual edit.
>
> -- [In Defense of Editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)

If you feel the edit is *critically important*, then you should flag the post for moderator attention so a moderator can come and lock the post while the issue is being reviewed. Otherwise, just *walk away* - there's no point in getting into a fight over something trivial.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you shouldn't actually be the one to start a rollback-war.  Rolling back the problematic edit (possibly with a comment explaining why, if it's not obvious) is fine.  However, if your rollback is rolled back, it's typically not productive to rollback the rolled-back rollback.

The general course of action in a case like this should be to…

1. Open a meta discussion regarding the post.  Basically, this is where you and the roller-backer would each argue why you think your version of the post is the one that should be kept and/or why the other version should *not*.  The community can then weigh in on the merits of the edits (and whatever else needs weighing in on).
2. Leave a link to the meta discussion on the disputed post.
3. Flag the post for moderator attention, explaining in the description field that it's a content dispute.  Moderators can lock a post preventing further edits/comments/voting/whatever until the dispute is resolved.
4. Discuss the issue with the community for as long as it takes to actually reach a clear resolution (or, if necessary, for a moderator to make an informed judgement call). This isn't always a case of simply deciding which of the two edits is more "right" (and is rarely if ever a case of "which argument has the most upvotes"), as it's very possible that discussion can result in a third option presenting itself as a compromise, or even bring up deeper problems — not only in the disputed post, but in the question itself — that weren't even considered originally. Don't be afraid to spawn new meta discussions when necessary.
5. If the original post is still locked (which is not always the case, as locks can dissolve naturally over time), flag again for moderator attention to remove it.
6. Apply the resolution to the disputed post; add a link to the meta discussion in the revision history for reference.

At this point, if anyone chooses to keep rolling back the edits after a clear community resolution and/or moderator decision has been reached, it should be flagged for moderator attention: Action (possibly suspension) may need to be taken against that user.

All this is of course assuming that there's actually a valid point of dispute; if the disputed edits are already *clearly* against Stack Exchange or community norms (e.g. introducing blatant vandalism or offensive text), you can probably skip straight to the end with "flag problem user for moderator action".  But when in doubt (and let's be honest, meta discussions aren't always as clear resolution-wise as we'd like them to be) bringing it up on meta pretty much never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

Your roll-back attempt Sohaeb in no way seemed like an ethically motivated action, because:

- You first rolled back the answer without explaining why;
- In response to my protest and roll-back you only said something like I'm not
  allowed to do so without citing any specific SE rule
- When I defended my edits, you then cited a moderator's opinion, which you also
  [posted](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1147/4058) to a recent meta question that I had opened, which reads:

  > Editing posts without questioner consent is fine for the most part, as long as the edits **don't fundamentally change the meaning of
  >   the post** (i.e. what the questioner is actually asking). Even if the
  >   questioner rejects your edits and insists on his own version it should
  >   be read critically to see what (if any) meaning is actually being lost
  >   (it's not uncommon for even well-intentioned edits to lose important
  >   nuance that's present in the original post)

First off, the quoted opinion talks about questions not answers.
Second, given that the rule, "not fundamentally changing the meaning of the post", also applies to edits made to answers, then I saw the criteria as perfectly applying to my edits to the answer in question because I made no fundamental change in the meaning or general theme of the answer whatsoever. Plus the original poster is very likely to have no objection to my edits because I had already edited some of his other answers in the past and he raised no objection. In fact he welcomed them!

Comment: I apologize. I did that move because the general rule is to go back to the original and then open a meta discussion about it. However, you were also guilty too when you decided to roll back too. anyway. I learned something which is a good thing.